# How to mutate nested object using graphql

Tags: graphql

I have a mongoose schema like the one below:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  owner: {
    type: String
  },
  member: {
    type: String
  },
  updatedDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  folder: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Folder'
  },
  dataSources: [{
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    updatedDate: {
      type: Date
    },
  }],
  propjectHistory: [{
    no: {
      type: Number
    },
    member: {  // is this reference or just a string?
      type: String
    },
    action: {
      type: String
    },
    updatedDate: {
      type: Date
    },
  }]
})

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema)
```

And I integrated with graphql using graffiti and graffiti-mongoose.
However, the Graphiql documentation shows that I only have the ones below:

```
addProject(input: addProjectInput!):

name: String
owner: String
member: String
updatedDate: Date
description: String
folder: ID
clientMutationId: String!
```

I could successfully add project with a mutation query only using those parameters, but it seems that I cannot even send mutation query with projectHistory and dataSource, which are embedded inside project schema.

However, I can access projectHistory and dataSource when I send find queries.

I can't find any documentation about the problem.

sample mutation query without nested ones works.

```
mutation {
  addProject(input:{
    clientMutationId: "1"
    name: "testproject",
    owner: "keonwoo",
    member: "keonwoo",
    updatedDate: "2015-07-24T13:23:15.580Z",
    description: "this is test project",
    folder: "56fb93403eab9e1c14358fb7"
  }){
    clientMutationId
    changedProjectEdge{
      node{
        _id
        name
        updatedDate
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the above mutation returns the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "addProject": {
      "clientMutationId": "1",
      "changedProjectEdge": {
        "node": {
          "_id": "56fb93ab3eab9e1c14358fb8",
          "name": "testproject",
          "updatedDate": "2015-07-24T13:23:15.580Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not using client like relay.

Comment: In order to help, I would need to see your client side mutation, and your serverside mutation. I am using nested types (with further nested types) and I have had no problems.

Comment: @sboutzen I added some more information, but serverside mutation is generated by graffiti-mongoose and I am not using things like relay. So there is not much I can provide... Would using graffiti-mongoose be a problem?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't tried graffiti-mongoose, so I might not be of much help. However, I can say that in your mongoose document, projectHistory and documentSource are set to lists of generic objects with some fields, which I could imagine being a problem. You could try making a subschema for those two types, and then use them like `projectHistory: {type: [projectHistorySchema]}`.

Comment: Also, when using complex types in mutations, you need to use GraphQLInputObjectType's, so you could try and create two input types, one for each of those fields, and then use that type in your mutation.

Comment: @sboutzen You were right, the problem was with the graffiti-mongoose library. Turns out that maintainers of graffiti-mongoose just added embedded object feature and I did not update. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your welcome, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the graffiti-mongoose library.

Turns out that maintainers of graffiti-mongoose just added embedded object feature and I did not update.